# Angular 8 Springboot File Upload hopeless

Tags: angular, spring-boot

Google 'Angular 8 Springboot File Upload'. I tried the first 3 pages. Couldn't upload a damn file.

Furthest I got was:

Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request]

Tried everything I could.

I just want to send a file from Angular and receive it in a spring boot rest controller.
Could someone please help me out with that?

Back End:

```
@PostMapping("/users/profile/upload")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadData(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
        throws Exception {
    if (file == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("You must select the a file for uploading");
    }
    String originalName = file.getName();

    // Do processing with uploaded file data in Service layer
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(originalName, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Front end service:

```
uploadFile(file: File): Observable<any> {

const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('file', file, 'file');
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
});
const options = { headers };

return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/profile/upload`, formData, options);
}
```

Comment: can you show you API code and how you are consuming api?

Comment: @Mustahsan sure! Just added them

Comment: did you tried making http call without headers?

Comment: @Mustahsan yes I did. Same result : [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request]

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good to me. You don't need to add the headers in Angular, and you don't need to send `options`, but I don't think it makes a difference.

I wonder if Angular actually sends a file. You can check with `console.log(file)`, which you can add in your front-end service.

You may also check what comes into Spring Boot. How about changing the signature to

`public ResponseEntity<String> uploadData(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception`

This allows you to X-ray to request, and see what's coming through. I hope these pointers are useful.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I had to add the Authorization header and it works